# Collections counter, adding lists wont work, if key is not existing

Tags: python

I am trying to count list elements values in two dicts. When in both Dicts the keys exists, it works, if i remove a key, it will throw an error. Is there another convenient way of combining dicts?

**This works:**

```
from collections import Counter

B = Counter({'a':[3], 'b':[4], 'c':[5]})
C = Counter({'a':[19], 'b':[4], 'c':[5] })
print B+C

>>> Counter({'c': [5, 5], 'b': [4, 4], 'a': [3, 19]})
```

**This doesn't:**

```
from collections import Counter

B = Counter({'a':[3], 'b':[4], 'c':[5]})
C = Counter({'a':[19], 'b':[4] }) #<--- c removed
print B+C

>>> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Comment: A `Counter` defaults to `0` for a missing key, so this is trying to do `[5] + 0`. You should probably use `defaultdict(list)`, instead (`Counter` is basically `defaultdict(int)` with some extra methods). Why were you using `Counter` in the first place?

Comment: Just to combine the dicts.

Comment: So you needed the `__add__` implementation? `defaultdict` doesn't have that, unfortunately; you may need to create your own class for the neatest implementation.

Comment: As of Python 3.8.10, using 'B+C' doesn't work even when similar keys are present in both Counters. However, using `B.update(C)` works for both scenarios mentioned by the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the dictionary update method?

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> A = Counter({})
>>> B = Counter({'a':[3], 'b':[4], 'c':[5]})
>>> C = Counter({'a':[19], 'b':[4] })
>>> A.update(B)
>>> A
Counter({'c': [5], 'b': [4], 'a': [3]})
>>> A.update(C)
>>> A
Counter({'c': [5], 'b': [4, 4], 'a': [3, 19]})
```

Or if that is a hard workaround because you have a lot of counter dictionaries, you could use python3 and try:

```
from collections import Counter
import collections

A = Counter({})
B = Counter({'a':[3], 'b':[4], 'c':[5]})
C = Counter({'a':[19], 'b':[4], 'c':[5] })
D = Counter({'a':[20]})
all_objects = vars()
all_object_keys = list(all_objects.keys())

for i in all_object_keys:
    if i != 'A' and type(all_objects[i]) == collections.Counter:
        A.update(all_objects[i])

print(A)
```

> Counter({'a': [19, 20, 3], 'c': [5, 5], 'b': [4, 4]})

Comment: @user1767754 have *you* tried it? It's hardly unclear how to apply it! It will only work if all keys are in `B`, though...

Comment: @user1767754 what if you create a new Counter dictionary and then update B and C to that dictionary?

Comment: This is a hard workaround, lets assume i have 100 dictionaries like this.